# Why don't we take this term $D_{\mu}D_{\nu}F^{\mu\nu}$ in Lagrangians?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, gauge-theory, field-theory

Why don't we take 
$$D_{\mu}D_{\nu}F^{\mu\nu}$$
in Lagrangians?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the more upvoted answer said, if there are color indices then the covariant derivative doesn't commute with itself and the expression you wrote makes sense.  If not, symmetry arguments about the symmetric nature of the derivative and the connection and the anti-symmetric nature of the curvature tensor are enough to reason like I did below that the argument is zero.  The two derivatives are symmetric, and the curvature is anti-symmetric, and so you are contracting a symmetric matrix with an anti-symmetric one, which is zero.
$$
D_{\mu}D_{\nu}F^{\mu \nu} = -D_{\mu}D_{\nu}F^{\nu\mu} = -D_{\nu}D_{\mu}F^{\nu\mu} =-D_{\mu}D_{\nu}F^{\mu \nu} \implies D_{\mu}D_{\nu}F^{\mu \nu} = 0
$$

Comment: The covariant derivative $D_{\mu} = \partial_{\mu} + A_{\mu}$ doesn't commute with itself, even in the $U(1)$ case: $[D_{\mu},D_{\nu}]=\partial_{\mu}A_{\nu} - \partial_{\nu}A_{\mu}=F_{\mu\nu}$.

Comment: @Olof Oh duh, you are right!  I was only thinking of the partial derivative part in my mind... My bad.  It's the definition of the curvature lol.  I agree.

Answer (score 10):

We do if there is a color trace. The term $D_{\mu}D_{\nu}F^{\mu\nu}=\frac{1}{2}[D_{\mu},D_{\nu}]F^{\mu\nu}$ is proportional to $F_{\mu\nu} F^{\mu\nu}$.